NFS drive not connected on Windows startup
I have a NFS drive mounted on my Windows 11, that connects to NFS on my server. Drive is mounted as a drive X:.
The problem is, that every time I start my Windows, that drive is "not connected" or something. In File Explorer ❌ is shown on my drive. If I click on it, it connects automatically and shows my files, like it's supposed to.
I want the drive to connect automatically, when I start Windows. I want this, because every time some other program wants to access it (e.g. Syncplay in my case), it fails to open my files. It's kind of annoying, because I have to make it manually connect first, before other programs can access it.

Only a poor workaround, but you can cause Windows Explorer to try to open the X: drive, if that helps.

Make a desktop shortcut, C:\Windows\explorer.exe /root, X: (you might find using the UNC path, rather than the drive letter, works better).

Place the shortcut directly in C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup and it will open Explorer on startup, but leaving that app open.

Alternatively, make a batch file with the following two lines, and plcae it in Startup:
C:\Windows\explorer.exe /root, X:
taskkill /im explorer.exe 

That opens Explorer and kills it immediately. If you don't want to see the apps open and close, use a shortcut to the batch file with it set to run minimized.
N.B.: Note that it attempts to close all Explorer instances, but on this PC, at least, it did not kill the essential Explorer instance used for the Desktop. Test this before deploying permanently.



I made something different, thanks for the idea. I made a .bat, that runs mount command on startup. Drives get connected after that. I think it's a bit better than killing explorer.

@Peter, yes, so please add details of how you made the batch file, and make it an answer that would help others! It's quite alright to answer your own question.

I ended up using following solution. I simply mount my drives every time on startup.
Probably not ideal to mount it every time, but it's one way to have the drive connect behind the scenes.

Create mount-nfs.bat script
Inside write your mount command:
mount -o anon \\192.168.1.100\srv\nfs\downloads X:

Create shortcut to the script, mount-nfs.bat.ink and set it to run minimized
Click shortcut properties, select tab "Shortcut" and select "Run: Minimised"

Add shortcut to start-up
Copy it to startup directory:
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Start-up


